# missing Web API controller class template VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-web-api

In VS 2010 **WEB FORMS** project, I used nuget "install-package Microsoft.aspnet.webapi".

PM> install-package Microsoft.aspnet.webapi
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 4.0.20505.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 4.0.20505.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 4.0.20505.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.0.20505.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 4.5.1)'.
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 4.0.20505.0' installed.

However, when I go to "Add new item...", under installed templates, "Web API Controller Class" is NOT available.  What else do I need to install to make the template show up.  I DO NOT have MVC4 installed, do I need it also before the template will show up?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuget gives you only the assemblies required to run Web API.

To use MVC4 Web Api Visual Studio template you have to install MVC4 package from here - http://www.asp.net/web-api. Once that's installed, in the "create new project" wizard you'd have to choose MVC4 template, and in the next window you can choose Web API project.

Note, that this is not necessary if you don't explicitly need an MVC4 applications. You can use Web API with pretty much anything - MVC3, with Web Forms, with console apps, WPF apps.. It's not dependant in any way on MVC4.

Comment: i have the same issue. as u said, i have asp.net MVC 4 installed and i am able to create mvc webapi project as well. but with webforms i am not getting webapi controller class template ins VS 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the target framework to 4.0 fixed the same issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install ASP.NET MVC4 for the templates to appear in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today. Even though i had all the dlls installed. then i simply created a new "website" instead of "Web application" and webapi controller class template appears in the template list.

Strange but worked for me. you can try it too.

On the other hand, You can install System.Web.Http dll from NuGet. then you can inherit your CustomController class from ApiCOntroller class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you need to have the target framework set to .NET 4.x in order to see the ASP.NET MVC 4 template.